# Migrating javaScript to TypeScript in Cloud Functions for Firebase for android

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to migrate my existing project's Firebase functions written in js to ts because of its advantage. But in the official documentation, there is no good example- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript. Is there any complete example or video related to this. Do I have to change the whole code written in js?

Comment: All JavaScript is already valid TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, All JavaScript is already valid TypeScript but now I want to use async-await. So how to migrate?

Comment: You dont need to convert your code to TypeScript to use async/await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function